# Is there a way to plot graph in julia while executing loops?

Tags: plot, julia

Let us consider the following scenario .

```
     for x in range (1,100)
         for y in range (2,500)
                 #plot(f(x),g(y))
         end
     end
```

where f(x) and g(y) are some user defined functions.

The output must be the desired points on plane.

Is there any way in julia to do like what I need ?

In general I can do like this

```
     for x in range (1,100)
         for y in range (2,500)
                 push!(l,f(x))
                 push!(m,g(y))
         end
     end
```

and then plotting from the two lists l,m as x,y axes respectively.

But now I want to plot points while executing loop.

Comment: You can do this with `Winston`, see `oplot`.

Comment: Where do you want the plots to appear?  In separate files?  Each plot in its own Window? Or ... ?

Comment: @StevenG.Johnson In only one plot.

Answer (score 4):

This is mostly supported in Plots... see https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl/issues/30 for a little more information and some example usage.

Comment: [The examples on the front page of the Plots.jl docs also shows how to do this](https://juliaplots.github.io/). @hanugm If Plots.jl's `plot!` functionality answered your question, please mark this as answered. If not, please comment on why this does not answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

use the `display` function:

```
for x in 1:100
          p = plot(f(x),g(y))
          display(p)
          sleep(1)
 end
```

(inspired by *Andreas Peter* on the Julia slack #helpdesk channel)